# django join select related

Tags: django, django-models

I have a category model that looks like this.

```
class categories(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=50,db_index=True)

class tag_relation(models.Model):
    category=models.ForeignKey(categories,db_index=True)
    relation=models.ForeignKey(main_tb,db_index=True,related_name='categoryrelation')

class main_tb(models.Model):
    name=charfield
    img_file=charfield etc..
    location=charfield
```

Now what I need to do is to select a particular category and further filter it using location.

What I am doing is this.

```
query=tag_relation.objects.filter(category='1orsomeother').selectrelated('categoryrelation').filter(location='india')
```

I know this isn't the right method but how am I supposed to do a join and search giving best performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this:

```
query = tag_relation.objects.filter(category__id=cat_id, relation__location='india')
```